# MVC Framework Suggestion for an HTML5 Canvas Based App

Tags: backbone.js, html5-canvas

I'm trying to develop an HTML5 Canvas based app. The app is basically a financial data visualisation app, that fully runs on HTML5 Canvas i.e. every button, event handling, graphs everything is done in HTML5 Canvas.

So far, I've used two libraries to manage the huge codebase:

1. jCotton for drawing and event handing, we had to modify and add extensive other functionalities to jCotton and it's working very well for us
2. RequireJS for modularisation which is also working fine

However, since we were at prototype phase, we did not invest in a proper MVC framework, so separation of concerns i.e. Data models, exclusives views were not properly maintained, as it was a proof-of-concept project back then, but now I'm thinking of refactoring the code and use a heavy duty MVC framework to better organize my codebase.

Now here is a the problem I'm facing, I'm really confused on what framework to choose. There are Backbone, EmberJS, SpineJS etc. All of them seems to be very good. But I can't make any optimal decision on any of them. I'm no JS expert, I'm been coding JS for only 1 year, so that's another reason why I'm having these difficulties.

A lot of these frameworks seem to put great emphasis on DOM manipulation which is unnecessary for my project, we have our custom data structure to represent the scenes in Canvas. The JS client uses a custom xml for it's communication and data-passing with the back-end server. I've been digging Backbone for a while. The Router would be of no use for me as the App runs inside the Canvas. The event based model however seems pretty attractive.

I'm wondering if any of you have faced similar situations and what you did for that. Should I go for Backbone, EmberJS etc or should I be better off designing my own minimalistic MVC framework. Which one should I choose If you suggest I use a third party MV* framework? As I said, I've been digging Backbone to see whether it fits my needs, I'd like to know more about other frameworks in this particular niche.

Comment: I don't know the answer; but one thing is, you probably want to find the most minimalist framework you can find -- the reason being any HTML-predicated features will be wasted in a canvas app.  That said, Backbone seems like a reasonable choice, but Spine might be better as, from what I've seen, it is smaller still, and doesn't even require JQuery to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a canvas-based "interactive time-trend chart" using EmberJS, and had a positive experience. You are not required to use HTML/Backbone (html templates) with EmberJS.

EmberJS's automatically-propagated properties and computed-properties are a good match to a scene graph API such as jCotton.

I'm not familiar with jCototn, but at a quick glance, it looks like it would be straightforward to extend a CottonObject class from Ember.Object that automatically modifies a sub-tree of the scene graph in response to Ember property changes.